# Calling device ready from iframe

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to make master page concept using iframe the problem with it is deviceready is not called when iframe is ready so i need to call every cordova function using `winow.parent`

For eg. notification -> window.parent.notification
window.sqlitePlugin -> window.parent.window.sqliteplugin

but there are many function so is there a way where we can find iframe is ready and call the function
I mainly found this problem while developing in ios where as in android everything works good